# does exit() free allocated memory on both _SUCCESS and _FAILURE

Tags: c, malloc, free, exit

This a short snippet of code, with two calls to `exit(3)` in case of failure.
Do these calls deallocate memory allocated by malloc? Google search once says it does, and even more times, it doesn't...

Should I add free()?

Also: which is better `if (!word)`(it would also work for eg. word == 0 which is different from word == NULL, so I guess it is wrong) or `if (word == NULL)` ?

```
char *word = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    if (!word) {            /* or maybe rather it should be (word == NULL)  */
        perror("malloc fail");
        if (fclose(fp)) {
            perror("fclose fail");
            exit(3);                            /* exit without free ? */
        }
        exit(3);                                /* exit without free ? */
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better to add `free` as a good programming practice even though the OS reclaims memory. Who knows, the `exit()` which exists today might shift places tomorrow, thereby giving rise to memory leaks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, all memory is returned. BTW, what would you want to do with leftover memory after the exit anyway?
Or are you worrying about a memory leak in `exit()`? If the memory weren't reclaimed, it would leak a bit more with each exiting process, which is something no credible OS could afford. So, except for a buggy OS, stop worrying about memory and use `exit()` wherever you need it.

To answer the questions in the comments of your code, whether to free, I'd say it's proper software engineering to write a corresponding `free` with every `malloc`. If that appears hard, it is pointing to a structural problem in your code. The benefit of freeing all memory before exiting is that you can use powerful tools like valgrind to check for memory leaks in the rest of your code *without false positives* from the malloc you've shown us.

Note that after a **failed** malloc there is no point in attempting to free the result--it's a null pointer anyway.

And third, I prefer `if (pointer == NULL)` over `if (!pointer)` but this is totally subjective and I can read and understand both :-)

Comment: The problem is because in a month I have an examination, where every possible leak will be checked with valgrind -v and bounds-check tools. That's why I want to do it in a "perfect" way, with no leaks, I can't relay on system behaviour, I have to free everything without its help.

Comment: Then you have given the answer yourself: free() what you have allocated and fear no exam :-)

Answer (score 8):

After calling `exit` you're beyond `malloc` and friends but the OS reclaims everything. Think of `malloc` as a convenient intermediary between the OS and your process.

Comment: Not only that, but in most modern operating systems running on modern processors, programs generally run in virtual address spaces that have ranges mapped to real memory/swapfile.  As far as I know, once the program dies, the virtual address space dies.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note that at those 2 calls to exit you have - you have failed to allocate any memory, so freeing that pointer is going to be pretty pointless (and might crash, depending on how old your C runtime system is).

So, no, you shouldn't free it, because it doesn't exist.

I'd have said in the case of a fatal error like that, you probably don't want to bother freeing up memory.

However, if your program exits normally, yes, you should try and free up all the memory you have allocated. That can be quite tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

When you exit the program, all allocated memory is reclaimed by the OS (both the stack and the heap). Your program doesn't leave any footprint in the RAM, unless you work outside the program's memory through buffer overflows and such.